# How to merge a whole local table to another in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to find out how to merge a whole local table to another one.
That is, one command that will insert the data from TableA to TableB and delete TableA.
Is there such a thing?

I've seen I can move one partition at a time using:

`ALTER TABLE table_source MOVE PARTITION partition_expr TO TABLE table_dest`

But I'd like to do it with one command for the whole table.

Thanks

Comment: currently this is impossible

Comment: You can try to use third table with ENGINE=Merge, look https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/merge/